# How do I invoke a method of a COM object in C#, when it is obtained via a generic object (late binding)?

Tags: c#, com

I have the following code that returns a COM object using late binding, to connect to a piece of 3rd-party software:

```cs
object app = GetApplication(this.simVersion);
if (app == null ) return null;
```

GetApplication returns a generic object using Marshal.GetActiveObject to find the COM object the user has requested. It needs to be late binding, because **simVersion** is a user-specified software version i.e. the software versions each use a near-identical Type Library, but the Application definition will clearly be different.

I want to invoke a method on the **app** object called ActiveDocument, which I know always exists and returns a type of object that I can anticipate and cast to, something like:

```cs
HYSYS.SimulationCase hyCase = (HYSYS.SimulationCase)app.ActiveDocument();
```

But the above will obviously not work because **app** is a generic object, not bound to a Type Library with the ActiveDocument method defined. I found some other SO threads about invoking COM methods, but could not see anything that didn't involve using Activator to instantiate a new application, which I **do not** want to do here i.e. I need to get a reference to the SimulationCase object that is returned by app.ActiveDocument - this is a specific file that is already open on the user's machine.

Comment: dynamic app = GetApplication(this.simVersion);

Comment: I get a compiler error about a missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create' - which reference am I missing to be able to use this neat solution?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using

Comment: .NET 4.8 - I think I solved it, just had to add an assembly reference to Microsoft.CSharp, having just Googled that error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hans Passant for providing the answer in a comment, it was so simple! Just changed all my **object** types to **dymamic** and was able to just run:

```cs
dynamic app = GetMyApplication(version)
HYSYS.SimulationCase hyCase = (HYSYS.SimulationCase)app.ActiveDocument();
```

and where GetMyApplication() essentially uses the following to grab the application object:

```cs
(dynamic)Marshal.GetActiveObject(className)
```

I did have to set an assembly reference to Microsoft.CSharp as well to avoid an initial compiler error that I was getting for trying to use a dynamic type (targeting .NET 4.8, at least).